# Calculating time to heat up a flowing fluid. Units not matching up

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I have an electric heater that can output 915.4 kW of power. I have fluid (isobutane) flowing through the heater around 1 kg/sec. The starting temp is 172.5 °C and the required temp is 343 °C. The specific heat is 2512 J/(kg°C).

My understanding is that I can find the required heat using Q = m*C<sub>p</sub>*ΔT so I get:

1 kg/sec * 2512 J/kg°C * (343-172.5) °C = 410 776 J/sec or Watts

I want to find the time it would take to heat up to that temperature at that given flowrate. I thought of taking that quantity of power and divide it by the electric heater power which is 915 400 watts, but that yields a very small number and the units would not yield time as I would be dividing J/sec by J/sec which is dimensionless. How do I figure out the time to heat up in this scenario?

Comment: there's no time to heat up.  Your equation is steady state.  Ostensibly the time to heat would be the time the fluid is in the heater or less.

Comment: Time to heat up is just the time the fluid spends in the heater. So this is a fixed quantity in your case. If you want to figure out how much heat will be transferred to the fluid during this time, you need more parameters like heat transfer coefficient and geometry of the heater.